# How to execute a powershell script within C++?

Tags: c++, powershell

The point of the whole program:

Pass in a username and password to elevate a user's privileges so that if they are not a user that is allowed to access a protected folder they can still open and view it. The username is mapped in a `<map>` which contains a key to their folder, it searches for their folder then passes it along with the username and password to do the real elevation in the following powershell script:

```
param(
    [string]$username,
    [string]$password, 
    [string]$folder 
    )
    Write-Host $username $password $folder
 
    $securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force
    $credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $username, $securePassword
    Start-Process T:\folders\Explorer++\Explorer++.exe \\foo\boo\fileserver\allusers\specialUsers\$folder -Credential $credential
```

I am passing in the username, password, and folder into this script through the use of `System()`.

The c++ code to execute the script and pass in variables looks like this:

```
  String^ runCommand(string folder, string username, string password)
    {
        string explorerpp = "\\\\foo\\boo\\examplefolder\\Explorer++\\EXPLORER++.exe";
        string space = "  ";
        string quote = "\"";
        string start = "C:\\ProgramData\\Microsoft\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\System Tools\\Windows Powershell";
        string open = "open";
        string domain = "domain\\";
        string pwShell = "S:\\foo\\boo\\locationofscript\\pwShell.ps1 ";
        string parentFolder = """\\\\foo\\boo\\folder\\Parent_folder\\special_users \\""";
        string path = parentFolder + folder;
        String^ dir = gcnew String(path.c_str());
        string param = quote + domain+ username + quote +  space + quote + password + quote + space + quote  + folder + quote;
        string command = "start powershell.exe" + space + pwShell + param;          
        system(command.c_str());
        return dir;
    }
```

Note: The code looks the way it does due to a massive amount of debugging, I understand that I am probably using a lot of un needed variables.

When ran through `System()` or `_popen` it either opens up a .txt containing a script or errors out on the command prompt.

If I were take what the value of `string command` is and paste it into a command prompt I would get the script running correctly and then opening the correct folder.

What is the issue with C++ that is not allowing the script to execute properly when the command prompt is executing everything correctly?

BIG EDIT:

The error I am getting is `C:\OurProj\pwShell.ps1 : File C:\OurProj\pwshell.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system.`

I did just talk to the IT guys, and I am able to run scripts on this system, tried to make everything local, and if I run the script through powershell it works.

EDIT 2:

I have changed the Execution Policy as has been suggested, and it does return `RemoteSigned`, however when the code executes in C++ I am still told that I have scripts disabled.

Comment: Where is `command` actually initialized?

Comment: @Andrew accidently removed when formatting to post for stack overflow, it is added in the correct position now. Which is directly above the `system(command.c_str())` call.

Comment: On my system, the default operation from the command line on a .ps1 file is to open it in notepad.  (ie: if I run your command contents on the command line it will open notepad, not run the script)  This is on Windows 7.  You need to put `powershell.exe ` in front of your command.

Comment: @ebyrob I did try changing it to open with powershell instead of notepad, when that happens it blinks a red error message which I haven't been able to capture yet.

Edit: I have done as you suggested and it gives me `the system can not find the path specified`

Comment: I think you need to add `"start powershell.exe "` before you call your command: http://mrpowershell.blogspot.com/2013/10/how-to-cal-powershell-script-with-c.html

Comment: If you can't see the output either run your program from the command line or put `fgetc(stdin);` as the last line of code in your program.

Comment: If you're getting `the system can not find the path specified` you probably ran this command: `"C:\\ProgramData\\Microsoft\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\System Tools\\Windows Powershell"` which is not a valid windows command.  However all by itself `powershell.exe` should be a valid command on most modern windows machines.  Red text comes from powershell, that means you were on the right track.

Comment: @ebyrob I appreciate your help, I have put start powershell.exe in the command and I updated the main post with the error I am getting through powershell when ran through Visual Studios C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In one environment you can execute unsigned power shell scripts, but in another one you can't.  64-bit and 32-bit each have a separate execution policy for power shell.  Most likely you're running on a 64-bit operating system and building a 32-bit C++ program (default for visual studio).

You can get to a 32-bit power shell by doing the following:

On the Start screen, type **Windows PowerShell (x86)**. Run this as administrator.

Next run the command:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
```

Now you should be able to run unsigned local power script files from a 32 bit environment on your computer.

From the start menu you can get to either PowerShell environment, be sure the same execution policy is set for both using the command:

```
Get-ExecutionPolicy
```

Comment: I have ran that command in PowerShell as an Administrator and when I Get the execution policy it returns RemoteSigned.

But, I still get that running scripts on this machine is disabled as a security risk when I attempt to execute my code. Am I getting a different powershell when I am calling it through c++?

Comment: @BridgerWinter you need to set it for both 32 and 64 bit environments.  Try setting from inside your application if nothing else works.